# Cypress Fixture: getting ReferenceError when trying to use aliases

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress, I am trying to use fixtures in my code, and keep getting ReferenceError if I used it aliasname.variablename fashion.

```
describe('Fixture Demo', function() {

    it('This works', function() {
      cy.fixture('admindetails').then((user)  => {
        cy.log(user.username)
      }) 
    })

    it('This does not work', function() {
      cy.fixture('admindetails').as(user)
      cy.log(user.username)
    })

  })
```

I included both what is working and what is not. My question is how can I simple use user.username using alias? I even tried @user.username and it doesn't work. I am trying to make 2nd test work. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your second test case isn't a valid way to do this, your first test is the correct way.

`user` is just a normal Javascript variable. In your second test, you are trying to use the `user` variable before it has been defined, which is why you get the error.

Here is the correct way to use aliases, [from the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values):

```js
cy.fixture('admindetails').as('usersJSON')
cy.route('GET', '/users/**', '@usersJSON') // or another command that supports aliasing
```

Your first test case is also fine to use as well, if you need the fixture contents later on they will be stored as `user`:

```js
cy.fixture('admindetails').then((user) => {
  cy.log(user.username)
  /** add any other test code that needs `user` here **/
}) 
/** write the rest of your tests here, they will execute after the .then block **/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I found that cypress commands are async and I cant use variable reference until `.as()` is completed. Hence, I need to use `.then()` method, which will ensure that user variable is intialized and user.username is available.

More details:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context